# Drupal 7 site crashed after enabling module - No DB backup. What do?

Tags: 7, database, debugging

I enabled the blog module on a website, after that the site crashed.
The error is the same on everypage:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to
>   entity_views_field_definition() must be an array, null given, called
>   in
>   /homez.653/xxxxxxxxx/www/sites/all/modules/entity/views/entity.views.inc
>   on line 152 and defined in
>   /homez.653/xxxxxxxxx/www/sites/all/modules/entity/views/entity.views.inc
>   on line 175

Problem is that I don't have any backyp of the DB......

Any any idea on what should I do?

Thanks you per advance.

Comment: if you have access to your database via mysql or other means, take a look at the `system` table and look for `modules/blog/blog.module` in the `filename` field and change the `status` field in that row to `0` from `1` and hope for the best :)

Comment: @Jimajamma why isn't it an answer? 
Jean-Christophe Kleinbourg consider installing [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) and enabling daily backups (hourly for development). I know now it's to late, but it can help in the future.

Comment: @molot, it's a comment because I am making the assumption that the OP is really asking how to manually disable the blog module in the DB, not how to go about debugging to make it work with the Entity API module.

Comment: Thanks, I tried Jimajamma solution, but it didnt work. In the future I will take care of making backups before touching anything.

Answer (score 1):

The mention of "I do not have a backup of the DB" in the question/title makes it clear that you want to roll-back the change as opposed to debugging and making the modules work where it is - for that, you do not need a backup, but access to the code and logs.

Another way to bypass the blog module, an alternative to what @Jimajamma said is to remove the module from the filesystem. 
Remember to clear the cache and ideally rebuilt the module registry after these steps.

```
drush cc all --yes;
drush rr;
```